# Calling a python class method from an instance of a class doesn't work as I expect

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, and I think I'm trying to do something simple.  However, I am confused with the results I am getting.  I am declaring a class that has 2 class methods, add and remove, which in my simple example add or remove a client from a list class variable.  Here's my code:

## Service.py

```
from Client import Client

class Service:
    clients = []

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, client):
        cls.clients.append(client)

    @classmethod
    def remove(cls, client):
        if client in cls.clients:
            cls.clients.remove(client)


if __name == '__main__'
    a = Client()
    b = Client()
    c = Client()

    Service.add(a)
    Service.add(b)
    Service.add(c)
    print(Service.clients)
    c.kill()
    print(Service.clients)
    Service.remove(c)
    print(Service.clients)
```

## Client.py

```
class Client:
    def kill(self):
        from Service import Service
        Service.remove(self)
```

I would expect calling c.kill() would remove the instance from the clients list. 
 However, when I evaluate the clients list, it is showing 0 items.  when I call Service.remove(c), it shows the correct list, and removes it as expected.  I am not sure what I am missing here.

If it matters, I am currently using PyCharm with my code running in a Virtualenv with Python 3.6.5.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your current and expected outputs?

Comment: @Gigaflop In the print statements I would expect calling c.kill() to remove itself from the list, with the following print statement indicating only 2 Clients in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is using circular imports, as both files utilize each other. Also, instead of relying on the client to destroy the connections, use a `contextmanager` to facilitate the updating of `clients`, and at the end of the procedure, empty `clients`:

```
import contextlib
class Client:
  pass

class Service:
  clients = []
  @classmethod
  def add(cls, client):
    cls.clients.append(client)
  @classmethod
  @contextlib.contextmanager
  def thread(cls):
    yield cls
    cls.clients = []

with Service.thread() as t:
  t.add(Client())
  t.add(Client())
```

Comment: I understand that it uses circular imports, but I would still expect that the clients class variable would not have multiple instances.